# OnTouchListener on Layout being blocked by other views

Tags: android

I am working on some gestures.  I set an onTouchListener on the most outer linear layout.  Listening for gestures works, but only where there are no other views(text,images,etc).  Wherever there is a TextView or any other view, my gestures do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extending LinearLayout, leave everything the same but overwrite onInterceptTouchEvent as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

That should do the trick. Be careful, though, always returning "true" does not let ANY touch event pass to the children. Depending on what you want to do, you sometimes might want to return false.